# Removing return caret within quotes in a csv file on unix system

Tags: csv, unix, double-quotes

Can someone tell me how to remove special character like '\r\n' withing double quotes in a csv fiel?

I basically need a unix command or script which can do the job.

My csv file looks like this:-

ID,Name,Age,Address,Street
1,Raul,45,"NewYork",1211
2,David,55,"New
York",4576
3,Charles,32,"Boston",656
4,"Julia
Jones",31,"Boston",7567

I want my file output to be like this:-
ID,Name,Age,Address,Street
1,Raul,45,"NewYork",1211
2,David,55,"New York",4576
3,Charles,32,"Boston",656
4,"Julia Jones",31,"Boston",7567

I tries some commands like sed,awk but somehow couldnt find a solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -z flag to consume the line as one line, allowing you to process the carriage returns:

```
sed -zi 's/\n//' file
```